# Is query.fromLocalDatastore() exclusive?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, local-datastore

When you add `.fromLocalDatastore` to a `PFQuery`, does it query exclusively the local datastore, or does it query the cloud as well?

From Parse:

> Often, you'll want to find a whole list of objects that match certain
>   criteria, instead of getting a single object by id. To do that, you
>   can use a PFQuery. Any PFQuery can be used with the local datastore
>   just as with the network. **The results will include any object you have
>   pinned that matches the query**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PFQuery` query using .fromLocalDatastore() does not hit the cloud.

The reason is that is its behavior by definition but I also verified this to be true through network monitoring of a query both with and without the use of .fromLocalDatastore().